# Fixed positioned element with the same distance to another element when browser window is larger

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am struggling all afternoon to resolve a problem. Maybe this is a common question but I could not find anything similar in here or on Google. I hope you guys can help.

I have a fixed positioned element on the left of the page and I want that the distance between that element and another on the page be always the same when the browser window is larger. How can I do it?

Now, the other element has to be set in percentage while the fixed element can be or not with pixels.

Is there any css calc(), javaScript, jQuery, something you can think of to resolve this?

[image]

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="fixed"></div>
<div class="left-element"></div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 2000px;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.fixed
{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.right-element {
  width: 25%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-left: 75%;
}
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/viery365/bjrno78p/1/)

Comment: Relationship definitions seem very vague. Criteria could be far better defined. *"same distance"* ..same as what? What should be allowed to change and based on what criteria?

Comment: I think that is because what is the most important in this question is not the relationship between both elements but how a fixed positioned element (the right side of it in this case) can have always the same distance to some point on the page. But thank you for pointing out.

Comment: That starts to narrow it down but still isn't very specific. What is *"some point"* ? Can widths change? You aren't getting concept defined well

Comment: I'm also struggling to visualise what the desired solution here is.. to me it sounds like like you want something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/7xaum4yu/1/

Comment: @azium Yes, it is exactly something like that but the calculation being made on the the fixed square (so, it is the fixed square that grows having perhaps negative margins) and the right square having always the same width in percentage and same position in the page. Thank you very much anyway. It is very close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same solution as @Calvin Claus but with just a minor css modifcation, no javascript needed

```
.right-element {
  width: calc(100% - 400px);
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-left: 400px;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7xaum4yu/1/)

Update: Similar, but as you asked, the calc on the fixed element.

```
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: calc(75% - 200px);
  background-color: blue;
}

.right-element {
  width: 25%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-left: 75%;
}
```

[new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/02rjdwnk/1/)

Comment: It is wonderful, but can you do it in the fixed element instead? Using negative margin-left if needed because it grows with a larger window?

Comment: Ok, you are amazing. You just saved me hours of pain. Thank you so much and I am really glad that you answered my request.

Comment: Sure thing. I'm curious, what's the use case here? What are you making with this layout?

Comment: Oh yes, the fixed square is a logo that has a negative margin on the left (I am showing just part of it). Everything goes well until the window is 1920px wide. At that point the logo starts to be very far away from the rest of the content. With your solution I can set a max-width to the body in percentage to keep hiding the part of the logo that grows. I spent all the afternoon and you sent just some minutes. Amazing, really!

Comment: Ps. I was just thinking on the margin-left: negative, never on the width because it is a png and I like the size of it. I hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a simple jquery solution:

```
var distanceBetwennElems = 100;

function calcRightElemWidth() {
   var rightElemWidth = $(window).width() - ($('.fixed').width() + distanceBetwennElems);
   $('.right-element').css("width", rightElemWidth);
 }
```

Just call this when the document is ready and the window is resized.

Also I removed margin and width form the .right-element css, because this is done by js now:

```
.right-element {
   height: 200px;
   background-color: yellow;
   float: right;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bjrno78p/2/

Comment: Thank you! I am going to try it out:)

Comment: Should be able to get this effect simply using `calc()` in css without needing any script.

Comment: Yes I agree the calc() solution is better and is supported across all major browsers. I did not think about that. 
Using JS, however, you can dynamically change the "fixed" distance, in case you would want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the width of the left, fixed element, using `calc`.  Here's an example using `500px` as the desired distance between the elements, and `25%` as the width for the right-element.

```
.fixed
{
  // disired distance = 500px
  // right-element width = 25%
  width: calc(100vw - 500px - 25%);
}
```

Your updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bjrno78p/3/)

Comment: Thank you! I am going to try it:)